# Why does FORMAT_SHOW_TIME doesn't show the time when using getRelativeTimeSpanString?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datetime

This just gives me `Yesterday`, however I would expect `Yesterday, 11:00 AM` because I used the `FORMAT_SHOW_TIME` flag. Why doesn't this work?

```
android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
    currentTimeInMilliseconds() - 1_000 * 60 * 60 * 25,
    System.currentTimeMillis(),
    MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
    FORMAT_SHOW_TIME
)
```

Comment: What is `DateUtils`?

Comment: I think it's from Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString(android.content.Context,%20long,%20boolean)

Comment: @SedJ601 I am sorry, I didn't include it in the question. I added the fully qualified path, hopefully its more clear now!

Comment: I think you are using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long,%20int)) method. It's not going to show any time. It is going to show time as a time relative to now, according to the document. Things like `42 minutes ago`, `Yesterday`, `Tomorrow`, etc.

Comment: It's clearer now.

Comment: I think this method only takes one of two flags, `FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE` or `FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE`. I am not 100% sure about this, though. My Android is very limited.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, `FORMAT_SHOW_TIME` is only relevant to method [`formatDateRange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#formatDateRange(android.content.Context,%20java.util.Formatter,%20long,%20long,%20int,%20java.lang.String)). The documentation for [`getRelativeTimeSpanString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long,%20int)) says the only valid flags are `FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE or FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE` so I'd say it's working as intended